# iTunes KERNELBASE.dll crash - Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: itunes, network, windows, appletv, home-sharing

Since I have updated iTunes (11.1.3.8) on my home PC running Windows 7 Home Premium SP1 it constantly crashes after about using it for only a couple of minutes.

When I check the Application log on the Event Viewer, i see the following Error info:

> Log Name: Application
>   Source: Application Error
>   Event ID: 1000
>   Level: Error
>   Event Details: 
>   Faulting application name: iTunes.exe, version: 11.1.3.8, time stamp: 0x5274a87d
>   Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.1.7601.18229, time stamp: 0x51fb1116
>  
>   Exception code: 0x80000003 
>  
>   Fault offset: 0x00013219
>  
>   Faulting process id: 0x2328
>   Faulting application start time: 0x01cefe992ffab867
>  
>   Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\iTunes\iTunes.exe
>  
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\syswow64\KERNELBASE.dll
>  
>   Report Id: d3dfd01c-6a8c-11e3-a1e4-0024e812336e

I do notice another error that accompanies this erro very shortly after this event others.  Here are those details:

> Log Name: Application
>  Source: Bonjour Service
>  Event ID:
>   100
>  Level: Error
>  Event Details:
>  Client application
>   bug: DNSServiceResolve(6F91E66928E4AC5D._appletv-v2._tcp.local.)
>   active for over two minutes. This places considerable burden on the
>   network.

After some additional research, it looks like this error is a result of my Apple TV trying to access my iTunes library via Home Sharing.  I have Apple TV Model MD199LL/A running version 6.0.2 (6646.81.1) of the software.  My AppleTv is connected to my router wirelessly and my computer has a wireless network card (D-Link DWA-552 XtremeN Desktop Adapter) to connect to internet and LAN.

The culprit might be Windows Firewall, but I am not exactly sure what firewall rules I should be looking at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some additional research, the culprit was iTunes Match.  When iTunes Match tried to upload the music file that was not available in the iTunes store to the iCloud, it would cause iTunes to crash and throw the KERNELBASE.dll error.  I removed the troublesome file from iTunes and it works like a charm.